# What is another way to write this equations in this list?

Tags: list-manipulation, output-formatting

I have mylist:

```
mylist = {{6, 7, 6, 2}, {7, 9, 7, 3}};
```

Here are two ways that I write equations from `mylist`:

```
mylist = {{6, 7, 6, 2}, {7, 9, 7, 3}};
HoldForm[(x^2 + #1  x + #2)  (x^2 + #1 x + #3) - #4 == 0] & @@@ mylist
```

> {(x^2+6 x+7) (x^2+6 x+6)-2==0,(x^2+7 x+9) (x^2+7 x+7)-3==0}

```
    Table[(x^2 + mylist[[i]][[1]] x +  mylist[[i]][[2]]) (x^2 + 
      mylist[[i]][[1]] x +  mylist[[i]][[3]]) - mylist[[i]][[4]] == 
  0, {i, 1, Length[mylist]}]
```

> {-2 + (6 + 6 x + x^2) (7 + 6 x + x^2) ==
> 0, -3 + (7 + 7 x + x^2) (9 + 7 x + x^2) == 0}

```
myfun[{a_, b_, c_, d_}] := {(x^2 + a*x + b)  (x^2 + a*x + c) - d == 0};
myfun /@ mylist
```

> {{-2 + (6 + 6 x + x^2) (7 + 6 x + x^2) ==
> 0}, {-3 + (7 + 7 x + x^2) (9 + 7 x + x^2) == 0}}

What is another way to write?

Comment: `(x^2 + a*x + b) (x^2 + a*x + c) - d == 0 /. Thread[{a, b, c, d} -> #] & /@ mylist`

Comment: @BobHanlonThank you very much.